# How to set the homepage for users on Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-carbon

Is there a way to set the default homepage for users to be a Carbon workspace? I'd like to have users directly see a specific Carbon workspace when they login rather than the standard Foundry homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, through Control Panel!

1. Navigate to Control Panel (`https://your_url/workspace/control-panel`)
2. Click on `Platform Experience` on the left sidebar; if you don't see it, get your platform admin to grant you permissions to be a `Platform settings administrator` (correct as of time of answering)
3. Add the relative path of whatever resource you'd like, e.g. `carbon/ri.carbon.main.workspace.abcd/home`